# Is it possible to remove title in Dialogflow Facebook quick replies and print only the quick replies?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible to configure the response in DialogFlow in such way that
when I enter the Facebook quick reply I will leave the title blank?

I want the user to get only the options without a title.

For example if I have:

Title: Choose an item

Quick reply 1: A

Quick reply 2: B

Quick reply 3: C

Can I somehow remove the title from displaying on FB?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you see quick reply payload [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/quick-replies/) ,

The properties are,

**text** *String*

> Non-empty message text to send with the quick replies. text or
>   attachment must be set.

**attachment** *Object*

> An attachment to send with the quick replies. text or attachment must
>   be set.

**quick_replies** *Array*

> An array of objects the describe the quick reply buttons to send. A
>   maximum of 13 quick replies are supported.

Format must be like,

```
{
    "text": "Pick a color:", // non-empty string
    "quick_replies":[
      {
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Red",
        "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>",
        "image_url":"http://example.com/img/red.png"
      },{
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Green",
        "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>",
        "image_url":"http://example.com/img/green.png"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I little late but this is when I saw the post.  If case you strill need a solution I accomplished the aforementioned by using a custom payload like this:

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"generic"
      }
    },
     "quick_replies":[
      {
        "content_type":"user_email",
        "title":"Red",
        "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>",
        "image_url":"http://example.com/img/red.png"
      },{
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Green",
        "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>",
        "image_url":"http://example.com/img/green.png"
      }
    ]
  }
```

In the attachment payload you can create any rich content you like, card, carousel, etc. and then attach some quick reply buttons without a title.  Also in the quickReply section you can change the text for any other like user_email or user_phone_number.

Hope this help